# Calculate folder size for multiple folders

Tags: powershell, batch-file, directory

I would like to build a script which does:

- Calculate total folder size for specific paths;
- Display folder size per path in MB's (recursive sub-folders included, not displayed);
- Calculate total size of all listed folders.

This will be used in a back-up/restore script. Prior to making the back-up we would like to know the total size of the back-up, and also in which folders contains large amounts of data.

Output would be something like:

```
Total size: 1456MB
    C:/folder1 100MB
    C:/folder2 123MB
    C:/folder3/folder1 1233MB
```

Perhaps something very simple for some of you. I have searched and tried for a couple of hours but never got what I need.. Any suggestions which code language to use, or specific scripts would help!

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far and where you failed. We are not here to write all code for you ;)
Take a look at [ask] and [mcve].
Also in question of what to use, if possible allways use powershell.

Comment: The snippet in https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-FolderSize-b3d317f5 works pretty well actually. I was wondering if anyone had a script that would do exactly what I asked. Thanks for the advise :)

Comment: Again... we are not here to write code for you, neither to supply with scripts for basic tasks :) If you allready found a snippet that does half of your question, try to solve the problem yourself and if you encounter a specific problem, feel free  to ask for help to solve it.

Comment: Again.. Thanks for the advise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this.

Use: `Get-FileSize "C:\folder1","C:\folder2","C:\folder3\folder1"`

Output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           ----- 
Total                          1456.00
C:\folder1                     100.00
C:\folder2                     123.00
C:\folder3\folder1             1233.00
```

Doesn't throw in `MB` because of the calculations that SUM does...

```
Function Get-FileSize([string[]]$Array) {

$Output = @{}

Foreach($String in $Array){
    $FolderInfo = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $String
    $totalSize = "{0:N2}" -f (($FolderInfo | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1MB)
    $Output.add($String, $totalSize)
}
$Output.add("Total", "{0:N2}" -f ($Output.Values | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum)
$Output
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much, this is a great start for what I want to build.This is the output: 
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                     
----                           -----     
C:\folder1                     0,00  
C:\folder3\folder1         1,27
C:\folder2                     0,00
Total                             127,00

I will try to understand everything in the code and ask questions accordingly